# Why is the series named this way?

Tags: brynhildr-in-the-darkness

I've been watching the anime since yesterday and couldn't help but wonder why it was called *Gokukoku no Brynhildr* or *Brynhildr in the Darkness*. So far I have yet to see any mention of Brynhildr; is this some person later on in the story? Or another name for the protagonist?

Comment: Maybe [Lynn Okamoto](http://myanimelist.net/people/2711/Lynn_Okamoto) just likes germanic mythology

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Brynhildr** in this series is  **Kuroha Neko**. [Brynhildr](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Brynhildr) is mighty female warrior of Germanic mythology and the chief of the [Valkyries](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Valkyrie).

Neko's character almost portray the character of Brynhildr as mentioned in German myth. She is powerful than Valkyrie. She does not have any past memory. She gained her memory and became very powerful at the end in series.

*Brynhildr in the Darkness* trying to show the Neko in darkness or loss of memory. She only does not have past memory but also lose memory when she keep using her power.

Answer (score 3):

Spoiler alert!

> It could be because one of the main antagonists is called Valkyria, and she's Neko's sister. Since Neko is even more powerful than Valkyria, Brynhildr could refer to her. Plus, Valkyria is almost identical to Neko, but with white hair instead of dark (darkness). Also, her memory is full of holes, so she's "in the dark" about her powers and background.

Answer (score 0):

As confusing  as the explanation was by "MirrorOfTruth" given on 09-12-2014, I think shklim or shkler was trying to say the following: The refrence to Brynhildr, from the anime series "Brynhilder In The Darkness", refers to the female character Neko Kuroha. Brynhildr is a mighty female warrior and chief of the "Valkyries", which comes from German Mythology.

Neko's character almost portrays "Brynhildr" from said myth where as she is powerful like the Valkyrie, has no  past memories, and as she regains her memories she becomes much more powerful, like in the end of the series.
(I'm going to leave the last part out because it is the definition of the word "Spoiler") but lacking basic grammar skills.

Having said that, it is almost as damaging to the information given, as it is to the person lacking said skills.

Answer (score -1):

Brynhildr (also spelled Brunhild, Brünnhilde, Brynhild) is a shieldmaiden and a valkyrie in Germanic mythology.

Best answer I could find.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brynhildr

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this is connected to the series ?